# Python shell gives me error IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

Please help, I am absolutely new to this and need to gather tweets for Southwest. What I am doing wrong? And, what & where do I have to write if I want a particular company name? Thank you.

```
 line 32, in get_all_tweets
    oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1
    IndexError: list index out of range

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    alltweets = []  
    new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200)

    alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

    oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

    while len(new_tweets) > 0:
        print "getting tweets before %s" % (oldest)

        new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200,max_id=oldest)

        alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

        oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1
        print "...%s tweets downloaded so far" % (len(alltweets))

    outtweets = [[tweet.id_str, tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode("utf-8")] for tweet in alltweets]

    with open('%s_tweets.csv' % screen_name, 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["id","created_at","text"])
        writer.writerows(outtweets)
    pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #pass in the username of the account you want to download
    get_all_tweets("Tverichanka"
```

)

Comment: Please choose more relevant tags and title; this question is not about the shell.

Answer (score 2):

This error indicates clearly that your list `alltweets` is empty. This means the returned value of `api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200)` is `[]`.

It could be because of a few different issues. One of them could be that the `screen_name` that you use has a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Print out `new_tweets` and look at what you're getting. Your error is most likely caused by no `new_tweets` being found, are you actually downloading data? Otherwise you're trying to get the last element of an empty list, and getting that error.

```
alltweets = []
alltweets.extend([]) # if new_tweets is empty will cause alltweets to remain empty
oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1 # can't get the last element of an empty list.
```

Oh and I'm talking about the line right before the `while` loop.